# Allow users to set 'target' badges

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, badges, information-display

Is something similar possible on the SE network?

- It should be specific to each site
- would encourage people to attain badges (and as badges generally
  encourage better members, everyone wins)
- Tool tips with descriptions would be good too
- We could limit the number to something sensible (3,5...?)
- If no badges are selected, nothing new is displayed.
- By default the badges could be hidden by roll-over.

Here is a mock up of what I'm after:

[image]

This is purely a matter of convenience, and would remind me to do important things (such as review more).

#### Second iteration

What if the target badges were put *here*:

[image]

Comment: I've removed references to HUDs and games as people seemed to be getting the wrong idea.

Comment: Could  the six downvoters leave a comment/upvote the comment that best describes why this is a bad idea (especially when those who dislike it aren't effected)?

Comment: [Downvoting on meta is different](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/faq#vote-differences), but I downvoted because I think it's a useless idea. Learn to remember things.

Comment: I'm aware its different, but i see two separate reasons to downvote: This functionality is unneeded (so is the entire menu in my latest edit!) And it would take up space (my latest edit suggests it could go in the drop down menu, so no space used). I just want to improve my idea.

Comment: I love how this was downvoted when you proposed it, but then it got implemented and, as far as I know, people generally like it.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This has been implemented by the [new profile UI](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2015/04/two-new-user-pages-one-new-stat-this-on/)!

Answer (score 2):

You know what would be not terribly difficult to implement OR useful?

Make links to your badge progress as of N weeks ago on SEDE. For instance:
https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/7521/how-unsung-am-i (with a userid pre-populated)

That being said, I'm in the process of badge whoring right now, so this post may not be altogether useful.

Answer (score 1):

Honestly - one click takes you to your badges. Not high effort.

I'd far rather have less on the front page than more.

Comment: Pureferret wants to display a selection of badges that he doesn't have yet (he doesn't specify which).

Comment: But a different click takes you to the 'all badges' page, which has tick marks against the ones you have. Also no effort.

Comment: It's one click to get to the them, *and then* you scroll though to see which you've gotten and which you haven't. If you are active on more than one site remembering which, nd finding them and the explnation is more than *one click*. See my edit also; this doesn't need to take up page space.

Comment: you know you can go to the data stack exchange and write yourself a query that can tell you how long till each badge etc (or more simply - plug together some existing ones) - and set it as a bookmark if you like.

Comment: @RoryAlsop I know I can do that, but I'm only just learning SQL. I see a lot of the features on stack exchange provide a similar "Could be replicated by external means" functionality, but are still present.

Answer (score 0):

What's a HUD? Ah. So… What's a Heads Up Display? Mmmmh. What on earth are those badges taking up space for? Granted, the site logo is huge, but at least it wastes only screen real estate, not attention as well.

Stack Exchange is not a game.

No.

Yeech.

Comment: I'm not suggesting we turn Stack Exchange into a game. It's only a matter of convenience. There are certain aspects of my SE behaviour I want to alter (I don't review enough) and also badges I want. If I was reminded of them on the front page/screen it would be helpful to me. Perhaps it could be hidden by default, and revealed by a mouse roll over.

Comment: @Pureferret: Try a sticky note?

Comment: @animuson A what? =p

Comment: @Pureferret Top Google hit for “sticky note”: http://windows.microsoft.com/is-IS/windows7/products/features/sticky-notes Though if you use a real computer, something like http://www.kde.org/applications/utilities/knotes/ is more relevant.

Comment: @Gilles I don't get on with widgets like those. See my edit though; this doesn't need to take up page space.

Comment: @Pureferret: Then try a good old-fashioned paper [Post-It Note](http://www.post-it.com/wps/portal/3M/en_US/Post_It/Global/). The flexibility of the paper in the real world allows you to write it any way you want. You can even draw unicorns on it!

Comment: @animuson unicorns FTW!