# Is sharing ideas fine on meta sites?

Tags: discussion, close-reasons, off-topic, per-site-meta, scope

In my experience, sharing ideas (which are opinion-based and not really questions by nature) is fine in meta sites. The posts can be:

- **Announcement posts.** For example, in [Net Neutrality and Stack Overflow / Stack Exchange](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/297816/260800) it is specifically said that "if you've got something to add, please do write an answer!"
- **Observation posts.** For example: [Case Study: First Answer Bias](https://academia.meta.stackexchange.com/q/4414/14341) or [Technical support: rational vs emotion](https://academia.meta.stackexchange.com/q/4403/14341) in Academia Meta
- **Proposal posts.** For example: [Answers vs Advice](https://buddhism.meta.stackexchange.com/q/61/13525) in Buddhism Meta

So I think it is perfectly fine to sharing ideas on meta without asking any question. I want to make sure if my understanding is correct, because I have such an idea about [Stack Exchange vs Reddit](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/323375/260800) and am quite surprised when it is downvoted and closed.

Comment: see also: [Show your work: one simple trick to make meta effective](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/296339/165773)

Comment: @gnat it seems like the answer is pretty clear: yes. In that case, I wonder why my question is heavily downvoted

Comment: Remember the net neutrality apocalypse? I do. Good times.

Answer (score 3):

Oh, sure, if they are ideas about the Stack Exchange network, it's fine. That's where a [discussion](/questions/tagged/discussion) is for. The [usual criteria for subjective questions](https://meta.stackexchange.com/help/dont-ask) still apply, though in my experience they are more relaxed than on main sites. Also, try to fit your idea in a Q&A format, instead of providing a self-answer in the question itself. FWIW, I didn't downvote your question, but it doesn't qualify as an 'idea' in my book.

You could argue that the Net Neutrality discussion wasn't really about Stack Exchange; the same holds for a few other political items which have been discussed before. We've had a  discussion about that before, and the majority stance on Meta (with lots of users having valid objections) is that Stack Exchange, Inc. is allowed to bend the rules a bit on very special occasions.

Comment: Well, "difference between SE and Reddit" is too much like a poll and/or opinion based, hence I consider this off topic. Might elaborate in a new answer after baking it a bit.

Comment: What makes an idea an idea in your book?

Comment: [MW](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/idea) defines it as 'a formulated thought or opinion'. I'd add to that definition that it should try to solve a problem, not merely be a list of facts, which your 'question' is. I wouldn't even call that post subjective, though there could be some subjective points in that list.

Comment: It actually an answer to a problem in Academia Meta before porting as an idea: [When should we ask questions on Reddit?](https://academia.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1557/14341). I've tried to explain its importance, but maybe not enough

Comment: @ShadowWizard and Glorfindel: if possible, can you explain why it is heavily downvoted? Maybe some people find it on-topic and some are not, but the fact that it is heavily downvoted tells me that they are consensus on something. I wonder what it is.

Comment: @Ooker I can only explain my downvote, which I already did, can't know for sure about others who downvoted, sorry.

Comment: The *legal* name of the company is Stack Exchange, Inc. "Stack Overflow" is a brand name, no "Inc." after it. I prefer using the legal name since the latter can be confused with the name of the site, but feel free to use the brand name instead.

Comment: @Ooker I guess many people downvoted because you weren't really asking a question, i.e. you weren't really seeking input and discussion from the community. I'm guessing a lot of those downvotes wouldn't have taken place if you had instead asked, "how is SE different from Reddit" and put the comparison in an answer.